# Problems to install zoo package, Error: sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

Tags: r, zoo

I tried to install the zoo package via the R package installer:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/srues/Downloads/zoo_1.8-8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

but I get the following error

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/srues/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'zoo' ...
** Paket 'zoo' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
** libs
    *** arch - i386
    c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c coredata.c -o coredata.o
    sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
    make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: coredata.o] Error 127
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'zoo'
    * removing 'C:/Users/srues/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/zoo'
    * restoring previous 'C:/Users/srues/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/zoo'
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘C:/Users/srues/Downloads/zoo_1.8-8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

the line

```
sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

says it miss the directory or file. What I have to do to find this file or directory? Or can I install the zoo package over Rtool40?

Comment: It looks like you are using R-3.6, so **do not install** Rtools40, the structure/requirements changed. Instead install Rtools(35), and you'll need to add it to the `PATH`.

Comment: That was the problem, many thanks:-)